# Apache Fop manual start : "java -jar" is ignoring absolute path

Tags: java, jar, ant, absolute-path, apache-fop

I am experiencing a lot of trouble while trying to run a jar file in the terminal. Until now, my command line looks like this:

```
java -jar /usr/src/Apache_FOP/fop-2.3/fop/build/fop.jar
```

Notice that i have already builded Apache FOP from source using Apache Ant, and the fop.jar is running fine when i run this line in the same folder. The problem is, whenever i'm trying to run it from any different directory, (let's call it TestFolder), i get this error:

```
Unable to start FOP:
java.lang.RuntimeException: fop.jar not found in directory: /home/evandro.teixeira/TestFolder (or below)
    at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.getJARList(Main.java:71)
    at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.startFOPWithDynamicClasspath(Main.java:130)
    at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.main(Main.java:219)
```

I'm not really sure of how is this related to Java, ApacheAnt or ApacheFop, but for some reason the fop.jar file is indeed executed if ai run the command line like this:

```
cd /usr/src/Apache_FOP/fop-2.3/fop/build ; java -jar fop.jar
```

The problem with this attempt is that i can't pass any parameters to fop.jar that are not within the same directory when using $@ in a shell script, and i really need them to be outside the fop.jar folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: From the [**official** fop 2.3 qucikstart](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.3/running.html) *The usual and recommended practice for starting FOP from the command line is to run the batch file fop.bat (Windows) or the shell script fop (Unix/Linux).*

Comment: Looks like it is looking for its own JAR flle for some reason, and they don't know how to do it correctly. They should be using `Class.getClassLoader().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()`.

Comment: @elliott-frisch Thank you so much! I had not notice the already made script at the Apache Fop folder, now i have added that to $PATH and now everything is working fine. It solved my particular problemm, but do you think was it a problem with FOP or with Java itself?

Comment: It is a problem with FOP, as I not only already stated but provided the solution for.